# WPF control binding to a single variable

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I can't seem to bind a control's value to an object. I want to bind a `TextBox` to a `string` object, the idea is that when textbox's text changes, it should automatically change the object as well. couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here is what I have tried:

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string str;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = str;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="150">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,642,319">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding str}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="0,0,-120,-46" />
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" Height="23" Margin="0,28,-75,-51" RenderTransformOrigin="0.423,2.257" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So, when I enter something to the textbox and click the button, I should see the text in `str` while debugging but it is always `null`

Comment: You can access the TextBox in code behind directly if you assign a name to it: `<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  ... />`. In code behind: `var x = MyTextBox.Text` or `MyTextBox.Text = "Hello World"`

Comment: @croxy, Thanks, I know that. But the thing is, I have a full form consisting of 5-6 controls. I don't want to handle all of them separately at the end, manually.

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6022711/5453249

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview). You should create a class with a public string property and assign an instance of it to the DataContext.

Comment: Declare a public auto property for str - public string { get; set; } and set the  DataContext = this;

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Change the str to a auto property:

   public string str { get; set; }
2. Change the DataContext to:

   DataContext = this;

The DataContext is the class which will hold your binding properties/commands/events.
The properties/commands/events need to be public in order to be accessible by your view.

For the two-way binding to work, you have to notify to the UI binding that the property has been changed and for that you need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the class which holds the properties which have been bound in the UI. You will need a private property and you cannot notify from a auto-property.

Simple Example:

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _str;
    public string Str
    {
        get { return _str; }
        set
        {
            _str = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Str));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Comment: An auto property only works as long as you don't need to be notified about property value changes. Then you would use a property with a backing field, and fire the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the property setter.

Comment: This works, but preferably the DataContext should be a ViewModel.

You might get som inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931212/proper-way-of-implementing-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf

Comment: How do I also get it to work twoway? I mean, when I change the `string` object it should change the `Textbox's` text I tried setting the `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: You will have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the MainWindow class and call the event handler with the property name "str". Search for notify property changed wpf and you will get the code.

Answer (score 0):

First, data bindings in WPF only work with public properties. So you must explicitely declare one in your code behind (instead of `string str;`)

```
public string str { get; set; }
```

Second, the `DataContext` property of a view defines the object / class in which the property will be searched for the bindings. The line `this.DataContext = str;` in your example means that you want your bindings in the view to be looked for inside the `str` object (which is a `string`). You should replace this line by

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

so that the bindings will be searched inside the code behind of this view itself.

**Remark**
You *could* also stay with the line `this.DataContext = str;` if `str` is a public property and bind using an expression such as

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding .}" />
```

which will bind to the value of the DataContext property.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use MVVM light to do the binding.